# Make Minecraft server IP the same domain as the website

Tags: web, dns, minecraft

I am trying to figure out how I can make the IP of a Minecraft server the same as the website (two different servers: a Minecraft server host and a VPS for the website.) I am trying to do this without any subdomains. I've seen other Minecraft servers do this before, I just don't know how.

Some servers that do this:

[quantum-mc.net](http://quantum-mc.net)

[theseedmc.com](http://theseedmc.net)

[partyrealms.com](http://partyrealms.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Minecraft server and your website have different IP addresses, they also need different hostnames. You can, however, set up the SRV records such that the person connecting to you just needs to type in your main URL.

Let's say your domain is `example.com`, your website is at `192.0.2.1` and your Minecraft server is at `203.0.113.1`.

You most likely already have an A record for your website, something like

`example.com. A 192.0.2.1`

You will need another A record for your Minecraft server. Let's call it `mc.example.com`:

`mc.example.com. A 203.0.113.1`

Now you create a SRV record that tells the Minecraft client connecting to `example.com` where to actually find the server:

`_minecraft._tcp.example.com. SRV 0 25565 mc.example.com`

This tells the client to connect to `mc.example.com` on port `25565` with a weight of `0`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Edit: Seems that this doesn't work. Don't really know the problem, but I have some photos. [Images](https://imgur.com/a/FIA1W66)

Comment: Try getting the records you set manually using some DNS tool like nslookup, dig or drill and check if they are correct